# Como manter o scroll sempre no final da textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Como posso manter o scroll sempre no final da textbox? Tenho uma textbox, porém ela recebe muito conteúdo, e quando chega no final ela não acompanha e texto que excede, fica sempre no mesmo lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei essa solução aqui

```
textBox.VisibleChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (textBox.Visible)
    {
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.TextLength;
        textBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
};
```

Fontes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898307/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-text-box